# How to ensure if all the resources are loaded on a webpage using WebVIew2

Tags: wpf, webview2

[image]I have a WPF application that loads several URLs in succession. The purpose is to determine if a particular image is available for each page or not.

Currently, I am using **Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))**. While this approach works most of the time, if the website or network is slow, the script to check the image's availability may run before the page has had a chance to fully load.

Code to check if image is loaded or not is this

```
 var isImagePresent = await _view.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.getElementById('exerciseCautionId') !== null");
```

I've also experimented with using the **NavigationCompleted** event of WebView2. However, I encountered a similar issue where the event is raised before all the resources are completely loaded.

Instead of simply increasing the wait time to 10, 20, or more seconds, I'm looking for a more robust solution to ensure that the page is loaded completely. Do you have any recommendations or suggestions for achieving this?

Comment: Finding the element is not sufficient? You want to wait until it is completely rendered?

Comment: @BionicCode Finding the element is sufficient for me. But I believe it is being added to page at very later stages. Because I am not able to find it when NavigationCompleted event fires. I have to wait few more seconds after that. Attaching screenshot for clarity.

Comment: Your context is not clear. Do you want to manipulate the DOM? What is your goal? Depending on your goal there might be a different solution to favor. For example, if the image will be there for sure but you want to be notified about *when*, then you should poll asynchronously. In case you want to manipulate the DOM you must inject event handlers via a script to handle HTML events. You can then send messages from the scrip (for example, from the loaded event callback) in order to communicate with your C# client or manipulate the DOM directly from your injected script(s).

Comment: For example, when you send a web message using `window.chrome.webview.postMessage` you will be able to receive and process this message by handling the `WebView2.MessageReceived` event. The message could be a simple boolean string value like "true" or a complex JSON. You can use `bool.Parse` to convert the boolean text presentation to an actual `bool` value

Comment: @BionicCode That image is there based on certain conditions. This is a third party web site, which opens this page and response is based on the parameter passed to it. And if the parameter (or the symbol passed) is red flagged then this image will be there, else not. And that is the reason I am checking for this image to know if the symbol passed is red flagged by system.

Comment: If you pass arguments to the server or web application then you will likely get a response. You should check the API if there is a chance to handle such a response. This would be the graceful solution. Parsing the document for a potential element is not an acceptable solution, especially when the page is a 3rd party resource. Your application will immediately break if the image is hosted differently or the element IDs change etc. Maybe the 3rd party web resource exposes a proper e.g. REST service that you can query.

Comment: There is also a chance that the URL is different for the particular error case you are trying to observe. Although parsing the URL would be better compared to parsing the page content (of a dynamic page that asynchronously loads content), it still offers a very brittle solution that will immediately break when such details of the 3rd party resource change.